# Python hooking memory to know number of bytes used

Tags: python, memory, hook, progress-bar, loading

I want to hook the memory to know the number of bytes used to create the World objects in my game so as to give me some information to update the loading progressbar

http://www.pasteall.org/20441/python

Comment: First, we're not going to read that much code.  Second.  Who cares about bytes?  Why not could "objects" or something meaningful and directly available?  What's wrong with a simple object count?

Comment: My problem is that this world class creates the world for my game and i want to make a loading progressbar for its loading, can you give me some tricks for knowing the progressing values from it

Comment: @Menopia: "loading"?  Loading what?  Be specific on what is "loaded".  Once you've defined what is "loaded", define how to count the things which are loaded.  When you've define the count of the things which are loaded, you'll have a very specific question, which we can answer.

Comment: The world class loads some textures, maps and other things, but i don't know how to count these textures and maps so, i don't know how to provide my progressbar with its progressing values.

Comment: @Menopia: "i don't know how to count these textures and maps"?  That makes very little sense.   You're loading them from some source, right?  A file, perhaps?  You know what's in the file, correct?  You've seen it once before?

Comment: yes i am loading them from a file

Comment: In the comments to my answer you identified the data source as dynamic. You need to be more specific than that. Are you downloading images from a web service? If so, what web service?

Comment: @jhocking it's from a data base

Comment: @Menopia: "File"?  Does it have a size?  "Database"?  Can you do a `SELECT COUNT(*)`?  Please be specific, detailed, accurate and precise.  Please **update** your question with all of this additional information.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to implement a progress bar is by incrementing the progress every time you load another object. Depending on how many objects you have to load that may be granular enough, and is very easy to implement.

Comment: so, how to calculate the number of objects :)

Comment: Presumably you would know how many objects you are loading. If you are loading some sort of dynamic data source that doesn't tell you in advance how much data there is, your loading bar can't be a percentage of the total, only how much has been loaded so far.

Comment: Yes, my data source is dynamic

Comment: "If you are loading some sort of dynamic data source that doesn't tell you in advance how much data there is"... Good point.  Sometimes you can "scan" or read through the source once without processing it.  Perhaps saving it to a cache file and, also, determining the size.